# Display Pretty hostname in Terminal prompt?

Tags: prompt

My current ubuntu prompt is set as something like

```
athos@myT460pLaptopBoughtAt2016 ~$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

, where `h` means `Static hostname`, as seen, it's quite long.

On the other side, I've set the `Pretty hostname`:

```
~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: myT460pLaptopBoughtAt2016
   Pretty hostname: T460p
...
```

Is there a way to refer to the `Pretty hostname` instead of the `Static hostname` in prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace `\h` with the following custom function in your `.bashrc` (or where you define `$PS1`):

```
$(hostnamectl | awk '/Pretty hostname/ { printf $3 }')
```

That should do the trick.

You can test the output of the function by typing:

```
echo $(hostnamectl | awk '/Pretty hostname/ { printf $3 }')
```

On Ubuntu 22.04 and later, you can also use the `--pretty` option, which outputs the pretty hostname directly:

```
$(hostnamectl hostname --pretty)
```